Sourcemaps not working when debugging NodeJS CLI tool
I've created a CLI tool in NodeJS (package.json bin section) and I'm able to install and run my tool. However I was wondering how I can debug it. I've done the following already:
npx -y create-nx-workspace
> cli-tools
> stack: none
> prettier: yes
> CI: later
> remote caching: no

cd cli-tools
code .

The @nx/js:library generator resides in the @nx/node package
npm i -D @nx/node
npx nx generate @nx/js:library --name biss --directory packages/biss --publishable --importPath=@company/cli-tools --bundler tsc --linter eslint --unitTestRunner jest

Update the package index.ts
#!/usr/bin/env node

const cwd = process.cwd();
console.warn(`Current directory "${cwd}"`);

Update package.json
{
  "name": "@company/cli-tools",
  ...,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.12.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "biss": "dist/index.js"
  }
}

Build the package
npx nx build --configuration=production --project biss

Install Verdaccio globally (admin cmd)
npm i --global verdaccio
verdaccio
> http://localhost:4873/
npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873/
> Username: example
> Password: example
> Email: example@example.com

Publish the package to the verdaccio registry
cd packages/biss
npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873/

CMD (admin)
npm install --global @company/cli-tools --registry http://localhost:4873/

Now from any folder you should be able to run the tool

This test project is published to this repository
I tried the following already
Inspect flag
In VSCode => ctrl + , => autoattach => "Debug > Javascript: Auto Attach Filter = always"
Add breakpoint in VS Code
Then run biss --inspect from a folder, from within VSCode. I see that VS Code tries to attach the debugger, but my breakpoint isn't being hit

EDIT
If I add a debugger; statement somewhere in my code this statement is being hit. However I end up in the javascript bundle (index.js) instead of the typescript file. I can add more breakpoints to this javascript file, but those in my typescript file remain unbound

EDIT 2
I did the following change, adding/correcting the "sourceRoot" field inside the tsconfig, and including the source files. So now the javascript bundle mapping files (*.js.map) for example contain the following
{
  "version":3,
  "file":"index.js",
  "sourceRoot":"../src/",
  "sources":["index.ts"],
  "names":[],
  "mappings":";;;;AAEA,qDAA2B;AAE3B,QAAQ,CAAC;AACT,MAAM,GAAG,GAAG,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,EAAE,CAAC;AAC1B,OAAO,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,uBAAuB,GAAG,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC"
}

So now the sourceroot points to the right folder (%appdata%\npm\node_modules\@company\cli-tools\src), but when running biss --inspect vscode still doesn't show the ts file.
This is the folder where the tool is installed (%appdata%\npm\node_modules\@company\cli-tools). It contains the source files so that the sourcemaps can point to it when the tool is installed.

EDIT 3
I added the following launch.json file to the tool's folder (%appdata%/npm/node_modules/@company/cli-tools/.vscode)
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outFiles": ["C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@company/cli-tools/**/*.js"]
    }
  ]
}

Don't know if VSCode would look at it, but it still doesn't work anyway

In regular browser devtools you'd need to add your project files to Sources>Workspace, this needs to be permitted. Can't say about VSC

Thanks, yes I already attempted to open the folder %appdata%\npm\node_modules\@company\cli-tools in VS Code which contains the installed tool's compiled code (and source code too). Then tried running the command from this folder hoping the debugger would show the typescript code. But sadly this also shows the javascript file. The js file contains the sourceMappingURL=index.js.map. index.js.map has "sourceRoot":"../src" and "sources":["index.ts"], so I assume any debugger should find the file. Will be looking further for "vscode debug external sources" though

Link on sourcemap configuration

As for browser devtools, you need to explicitly allow it to use FS, as it can't access files without permission, so for some debuggers it's this problem. I can confirm that adding files to a workspace makes it work
